# Where to install "guile-git" on Ubuntu 14?

Tags: guile

I got stuck installing "git clone https://gitlab.com/guile-git/guile-git.git". In which directory is this supposed to be cloned and installed?

Comment: It will clone wherever you run the command. Where do you want it?

Comment: Ok, thank you. "Guile-git" is a prerequisite to install the guix package, and thus, it has to go somewhere into a system wide folder, e.g. /usr/bin. However, "guile-git" contains a vast number of files and subdirectories and no furhter instruction how to install "guile-git" after cloning it onto my system. How to go from there?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if you're still looking for an answer but it doesn't seem you need this installed to install `guix`; the read-me of the repository says that you can install it via `guix`. `guix` is an agnostic package manager that you can install on any Linux distribution alongside the default package manager and `guix` is *the* default package manager of the GuixSD operating system (https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/).

If you're on a distro which doesn't use `guix`, you may not want to install `guix` (I've yet to find reason enough to, yet); if you use a lot of GNU tools or Guile (some Guile packages are available through `guix`), you may want to.

Most repositories that don't have a binary for you to run follow the build process of `configure`, `make`, and `[sudo ]make install`.

I cloned the repository, myself, and find that this one does, as well.

Get a terminal (if you haven't been using one, yet) and `cd` into the directory you cloned the repository to and then `cd` into the `guile-git` directory (`cd guile-git`).

If we do `ls -l`, we'll see that the only executable file there is the `bootstrap` one; I've never seen one before but doing `./bootstrap` generates the `configure` file and sets up the `make` process for us. So now back in familiar territory.

Given these are Guile files, we'll probably want to install this under the same prefix as where Guile is installed so run `which guile`. I believe, if you install it under Ubuntu (I'm running Linux Mint), it'll install to `/usr/bin/` but, if you install it manually, it'll install to `/usr/local/bin/`.

The latter is where mine is and that's the default prefix that `configure` uses so I can just do `./configure`; if you wanted to install it under `/usr/`, run `/.configure --prefix=/usr/`.

This'll verify that all of the necessary libraries and programs that `guile-git` needs are installed and properly setup. Heads up that `configure` balked at me over not having the Guile module `bytestructures` installed (https://github.com/TaylanUB/scheme-bytestructures) so you may need to do that.

I'm not going to run through everything to get it installed but, once you can run it without any errors, run `make` to build it within the directory.

If you want to install it permanently on your computer with the rest of your operating system able to detect it, run `make install`. Since you'll likely've specified a directory under `/usr`, you'll have to do `sudo make install` so that the make process can have permissions to install under `/usr/local` or `/usr`.

Sorry if I reiterated anything you already knew; 'just didn't want to assume you knew something and result in confusion.